# How to remove one bar label from the legend in a multiple bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two bars in a barchart. However, I would like to display only one of the labels in the legend. Example:

```
In [190]: import pandas as pd

In [191]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [192]: import seaborn as sns

In [193]: from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

In [194]: my_cmap = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("GnBu_d", 4).as_hex())

In [195]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[200, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 120, 60, 20]], columns=['Total','A', 'B', 'C'])

In [196]: ax = df1.plot(colormap=my_cmap, title='Allocation per bucket', kind='bar', stacked=True, alpha=0.8)

In [197]: ax.title.set_size(30)

In [198]: ax.set_ylabel('Value', fontsize=15)
Out[198]: Text(0,0.5,'Value')

In [199]: ax.set_xticklabels(['Total', 'Split'])
Out[199]: [Text(0,0,'Total'), Text(0,0,'Split')]

In [200]: box = ax.get_position()

In [201]: ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])

In [202]: ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=13, prop={'size': 13})
Out[202]: <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x7f1ce0b4e050>

In [203]: plt.xticks(rotation=0)
Out[203]: (array([0, 1]), <a list of 2 Text xticklabel objects>)

In [204]: plt.show()
```

As you can see this leads to the following picture

[image]

I would like to have the `Total` be removed from the legend and only display there the `A`, `B` and `C`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `['A','B','C']` in `ax.legend()`. Your code line should look like:

```
ax.legend(['A','B','C'], loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=13, prop={'size': 13})
```

And you will eliminate **Total** from legend.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer simply renames the first 3 legend labels to `['A','B','C']` without actually removing "Total" (and doesn't show the last legend entry). This can be seen by looking at the colours in the legend. The colour for "Total" is still the first entry in the legend, however it has been renamed to "A". I don't think this is the desired result.

You can get a list of the legend handles and labels using `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` and then slice the result to not include the first entry:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[1:], labels=labels[1:],
          loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=13, prop={'size': 13})
```

Which gives:

[image]